# Tomcat - Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web

I run Tomcat 7 on my local development machine and my web app runs fine, moving it to the server (also running Tomcat 7), I started getting Error 500, complaining of some inability to compile some JSPs. I've restarted the server, but still doesn't fix it. Here is my most recent log. What could be the problem?

Here is a screenshot of what I got while trying to access the index.jsp at the context root (all other pages too do the same) https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B62YJhbvaJNkN3hjTUpEMVp1eUk
Somethings they may load after about 4 refreshes. I also saw some permGen stuff. Please I need help. Thanks!

```
    Aug 25, 2012 5:05:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LoginChurch] in context with path [/ReligionApp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry.reregister(C3P0Registry.java:239)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DriverManagerDataSourceBase.<init>(DriverManagerDataSourceBase.java:212)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.<init>(DriverManagerDataSource.java:60)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.<init>(DriverManagerDataSource.java:56)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.unpooledDataSource(DataSources.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.processRequest(LoginChurch.java:68)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.doPost(LoginChurch.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
Aug 25, 2012 5:06:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LoginChurch] in context with path [/ReligionApp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.pacesolutions.religionapp.HibernateUtil
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.processRequest(LoginChurch.java:68)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.doGet(LoginChurch.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Aug 25, 2012 5:11:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LoginChurch] in context with path [/ReligionApp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.pacesolutions.religionapp.HibernateUtil
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.processRequest(LoginChurch.java:68)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.doPost(LoginChurch.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Aug 25, 2012 7:18:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 25, 2012 7:18:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 25, 2012 7:18:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Aug 25, 2012 7:18:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

Answer (score 0):

The permen space is where the VM stores the class, methods (among others). As tomcat compiles the class dynamically, it can use too much of this space which has a fixed upper bounds (usually 64Mb).

Try to give more permgen space to tomcat with the `-XX:MaxPermSize` option.

Have a look at this article for an explanation : http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc/

Comment: Okay thanks, what of the other issues? Please note that I restarted Tomcat and the issues still persisted. Also please take a look at the link to the screenshot I posted. Thanks.

Comment: The other issue is a class not found.  Looks like you are missing something from the classpath - e.g. WEB-INF/libs.

Comment: It works properly on my local development Tomcat. Meanwhile, as a quick fix, I have swapped that Tomcat (on the server machine) to another port, then installed a fresh Tomcat at port 8080 and redeployed. But I'll like to know how to fix this in case I encounter it in future (and I think its very likely I'll encounter it sometime again in my career).

Comment: @dystroy I set the new Tomcat to 128Mb(min) and 128mb(max), do you consider that okay for a lab server (not where final productions go; likely to experience frequent redeployment of apps).

Comment: This is a pretty common value for this setting in tomcat so even while I cannot say for your server and its webapps, it's probably OK.

Answer (score 0):

The other issue is a class not found that is caused by the PermGenSpace OOM Error. So it is not relevant in this case.
Which user is running the tomcat server? Is that root or another user? Does this user have permissions to write in the directory stated by the last root cause in the provided stacktrace? See the `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: I think its runs as root because when I drop a WAR file in the webapps directory, the generated directory representing the context path of the deployed apps gets created by root. So the question is: why should it not have access to any part of the filesystem? Meanwhile, please bear in mind that this is not the first time I would be deploying iterations of this particular web app.